# Facing issue in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am facing issue while joining the three table Employee,Eventcelibration,emp_event.

Employee table has three fields birth_date,date_of_joining,Anniversary_date.

want to make a query on basis of above three column.if employee has birthday then select the birth_day description from other table eventcelibration and if he has joining date today then select joining message from the table. like wise.

made the query on some dummy data as below.

**Employee table**

```
id
employee_id
name
designation
contactno
email
birth_date
date_of_joining
```

**Table eventcelibration**

```
Event_cl_id
Event_type
frequency
description
template
subject
```

Third Table

**Emp_event**

```
Event_id
employee_id.
```

I have tried the query,

```
select a.employee_id,a.name,a.email,a.birth_date,c.template,c.description,c.subject,c.event_type from 
employee a  inner join emp_event b   on a.id = b.Event_id
inner join eventcelebration c  on b.employee_id = c.event_cl_id
where CAST(birth_date as date) = CAST(curdate() as date) or CAST(date_of_joining as date) = CAST(curdate() as date)
```

It returns us the three result but I want only one that is birthday , because birthday is today date.

Answer (score 1):

You are considering date datatype, which includes year.
In this case for an yearly event only month and day of month matters not the year.
I hope the following query would help

```
SELECT a.employee_id,a.name,a.email,a.birth_date,c.template,c.description,c.subject,c.event_type FROM 
employee a  INNER JOIN emp_event b   ON a.id = b.Event_id
INNER JOIN eventcelebration c  ON b.employee_id = c.event_cl_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d') 
OR DATE_FORMAT(date_of_joining,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: EMp:



3 19778 A Engineer   2019-07-19 1979-10-01   
4 19778 B Engineer   1979-10-01 1979-10-01   
5 53837 C Engineer   1979-10-01 1979-10-01 

Event celibration




    3 birthday
                  4  joining day
                  5 Anivarsary

Emp_event




3 3
3 4
3 5
4 3
4 4
4 5


This is the data.

not working yet.pls help

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/980744/3 Please check this sqlfiddle, this is working for me

Comment: I have different event celibration as one employee can have the birthday , and joining date in single date.

And the data of eventcelibration  is 

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/980744/3

If any employee has the birth day and joining day is same then there must be two event celibration one is birthday and other is joining .
so the template and description for both the event will be different.

pls help

Answer (score 0):

Select `a.birth_date` only in the select query.

```
select a.birth_date from 
employee a  inner join emp_event b   on a.id = b.Event_id
inner join eventcelebration c  on b.employee_id = c.event_cl_id
where CAST(birth_date as date) = CAST(curdate() as date) or CAST(date_of_joining as date) = CAST(curdate() as date)
```

Comment: It gives us the date only ,I want to get the description from the eventcelibraton table .Since this today is birthday .so i wan to pick the birthday message but it is taking all the data like birthday,joining and Anivarsary.